# Отправка файла на почту клиента php mail

Tags: php, html, email

Не могу найти решение в интернете, подозреваю, что не могу составить грамотный запрос. Суть вот в чём: клиент вводит имя, имейл; я их передаю ajax на обработчик php, отсылаю письмо клиенту на введеный имейл, с этим проблем нет, а вот как прикрепить к этому письму файл (pdf, doc..) не приложу ума.

```
<?

$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
if ($name == "" || $phone == "" || $email == "" )  {
    echo "Заполните все поля";
    die();
}
$email = strtolower($email);

$to = $email; 
$subject = 'Каталог';
$message = '
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>'.$subject.'</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <p>'. $name .', доброго времени суток. Высылаем Вам каталог.</p>   
            </body>
       </html>  '; 
       $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n"; 
       $headers .= "From: Отправитель".  $email ."<". $email .">\r\n"; 


       mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

Comment: Справшиваем у гугла: php mail attachment. первая ссылка http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail